# A package installed in an environment is also available in other environments, why?

Tags: python, anaconda

I'm trying to understand the logic behind `conda install` in various environments based on the following two cases.

On the **first machine**, I've installed fresh Anaconda 3 with Python 3.7, created new envs `py27` and `py37` for Python 2.7 and 3.7, both with default Anaconda packages, and added only one new `joblib` package to `py27` env:

```
conda install -n py27 joblib
```

After this operation, `joblib` is available in all three environments. Why not only in `py27?

On the **second machine**, I've installed fresh Anaconda 2 with Python 2.7, created new envs `py27` and `py37` for Python 2.7 and 3.7, both with default Anaconda packages, and added only one new `joblib` package to `py27` env, this time using a slightly different command:

```
conda activate py27
conda install joblib
```

This time, `joblib` is available in `py27` and `py37`, but not the base env. Why not in the base?

The **question:** the two commands are supposed to be equivalent, but the result in both cases is surprising to me. I'd expect that in each of these two cases `joblib` is installed only in the `py27` env. Clearly, I'm missing some information. I couldn't find anything about this in Anaconda docs, nor online.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that `joblib` is installed by default in Anaconda 3, but not in Anaconda 2. Thus, indeed `conda install` installs the package only in the env `py27`, but the package is available in all Python 3.7 environments, because it's added by Anaconda 3 distribution.